# How do I Retrieve -> View -> Delete File in PHP?

Tags: php, download, flush

Here is a code which retrieves a file (say .doc) from a server, stores it in a temporary folder and then uses an api (say google viewer) to display it and then deletes it.

```
<?php 
$body = "....."; //data from imap server
$name = "abc.doc";

$file = fopen("temp/" . $name,'w'); 
fwrite($file,$body); 
fclose($file); 
$url = rawurlencode("http://www.xxx.com/temp/".$name); 
// I do not have a direct url to the file on the imap server, thus have to store it in a temporary folder

echo "<iframe src=\"http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={$url}&embedded=true\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" style=\"border: none;\"></iframe>";

unlink("temp/".$name);
?>
```

Now the issue is that since the php script executes itself first and then echo's the buffer, the google viewer cannot find the file since its already deleted. Using flush() does not help either.

One work around is to remove the "unlink" command and create a cron-job to delete all files in the temp folder (say after every 2min). Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make the link to

```
echo "<iframe src=\"http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="http://www.domain.com/viewthis.php?name=abc.doc&embedded=true\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" style=\"border: none;\"></iframe>";
```

then make viewthis.php stream the file... then as soon as it's served, you can delete it.

Comment: I tried this but not working. I changed the link, where viewthis.php is 

$name = $_GET['name'];
$data = file_get_contents('temp/'.$name);
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
echo $data;

Comment: The issue is deleting the file. If I delete it in the same script which is echoing the google viewer, it will never work. Am I right??

Comment: It should stream it to the viewer and then delete ... the example in http://uk.php.net/readfile will show you how... if you do this it will send the content to browser, and at the point you unlink it will have been served.

Answer (score 0):

I assume (looking at the comment in line 2) that you are trying to view mail attachments. What you can do is dynamically create a file url for google to lookup the file. What you do is create a script, say 'view_file.php', which loads/downloads the file and pushes the file back, with some custom headers to tell the 'browser' (google) what kind of file it is. In this way you do not have to save the file. Downside is that the file will be accessible always from the outside, so you still should set a timer or something like that.

For an image you would do something like this:

```
$im = file_get_contents('http://www.site.com/url_to_your_image'); // or any other function to retrieve the image data itself
header('content-type: image/gif'); 
echo $im;
```

For any other file, just change the content-type header.